# Removing constness from reference returned by const accessor method versus adding a non-const accessor method

Tags: c++

Let's consider the following code:

```
Class MyVeryAccessibleClass
{
public:
    const std::vector<int>& getVect() const {return vect_m;};
private:
    std::vector<int> vect_m;
};

Class MyInitClass
{
   MyInitClass() : importantInt_m{10}{};
   void init();
protected:
    int importantInt_m;
};
```

My project is built in a way that it has to be MyInitClass::init() that initializes or modifies MyVeryAccessibleClass::vect_m.

Some other classes will also have access to MyVeryAccessibleClass::vect_m but I don't want them to be able to modify it, they should only be able to read it.

I thought of 2 solutions:

1. Casting away the constness of getVect() in init (and only there). This is the solution I am leaning towards, but I've read that const_cast should be avoided so I am not sure this is correct:

```
MyInitClass::init()
{
   MyVeryAccessibleClass* class_l = methodToGetMyVeryAccessibleClassInOneWayOrAnother();
   auto vect_l& = const_cast<std::vector<int>&> (class_l ->getVect());
   vect_l.push_back(importantInt_m);
}
```

2. Adding a non-const accessor to MyVeryAccessibleClass. I don't really like this solution because it means that if in another part of the code I use a pointer to MyVeryAccessibleClass, it will call the non-const accessor, and this accessor should only ever be used in MyInitClass::init()

```
Class MyClass
{
public:
    const std::vector<int>& getVect() const {return vect_m;};
    // I've read that I could also call the const accessor from here, but that is not really the point
    std::vector<int>& getVect() {return vect_m;}; 
private:
    std::vector<int> vect_m;
};

MyInitClass::init()
{
   MyVeryAccessibleClass* class_l = methodToGetMyVeryAccessibleClassInOneWayOrAnother();
   auto vect_l& = class_l ->getVect();
   vect_l.push_back(importantInt_m);
}

MyOtherClass::doStuff()
{
   MyVeryAccessibleClass* class_l = methodToGetMyVeryAccessibleClassInOneWayOrAnother();
   // I don't want that. 
   // I guess one could precise const auto vect_l& to call the const accessor or use the new std::as_const
   // But not everybody is familiar with that and I felt like I should not even allow the possibility of making a mistake
   auto vect_l& = class_l->getVect();
   // Mistake far less obvious than this one but that modifies the vector:
   vect_l.push_back(15);
}
```

Is there a better solution that I didn't think of ? And if not, should I go with solution 1 or solution 2 ? My sentiment was that since I only ever want to modify MyVeryAccessibleClass::vect_m in MyInitClass::init, it was OK to do a const_cast there and not have a non-const accessor in MyVeryAccessibleClass.

Comment: Make `MyInitClass` a friend of `MyVeryAccessibleClass` and access `vect_m` directly.

Comment: Or add a constructor that takes a `std::vector<int>` as a parameter and uses it to initialize `vect_m`. This is what constructors are for.

Comment: Always the same (similar discussions exist for `goto`...). You should read it as `should usually be avoided`. Sure one shouldn't use *in general* but almost always there are *valid* exceptions to the rule. Making `MyInitClass` a `friend` is pretty often a valid approach (and a good one), it might grant access to many more resources that it actually should touch, though, – or you simply cannot modify the class – so not the Holy Grail either. So in the end you won't find a one for all solution anyway, you'll have to consider advantages and disadvantates with your own brains and decide yourself.

Comment: One thing, though: ***If*** you opt for the `const_cast` I recommend to clearly document *why*, so anyone (including yourself after quite some time) can catch up with your thoughts.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I simplified the code a lot, and indeed `MyVeryAccessibleClass`  contains a lot of other members and I am not totally sure they are all meant to be accessible/editable by `MyInitClass` (I will have to double check that, it is a really big project).
I never used the `friend` keyword, I thought it was for classes that are very intricately linked to one another.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You mean a constructor like `MyVeryAccessibleClass(std::vector<int>)` ? The problem is that this class is constructed way before `MyInitClass` is constructed. So I don't have the vector available when I am constructing `MyVeryAccessibleClass`. Moreover, I don't actually use a member of `MyInitClass` to fill the vector, `MyInitClass` reads input from an xml file and adds a new value to my vector each time such value is read from the xml. So it's not really an init in one-go.

Comment: Just to be sure, the solution 2 is indeed the one I should avoid ? It's better to not have non-const accessors when possible ?

Comment: Any reason why the XML file is read that lately? That design has some smell in my eyes.

Comment: I could not say exactly. There is a functionnality where a xml tag is read and instanciates a corresponding class at runtime. Most classes are created when a xml tag is read, since they only depend on one tag. But for a couple of classes (such as MyVeryAccessibleClass) that store a lot of global data,  the class is created prior reading, and then filled with differents tags that don't necessarily have a relationship with each other. Afaik, those tags are not even centralised within the same global tag. Maybe that's why the xml is read so late compared to the creation of the class in this case.

Comment: I guess they could have stored all the xml values/tags needed for `MyVeryAccessibleClass` somewhere, and then call a giant constructor once. I don't know if it would have been better. But it has drawbacks, like handling cases when a tag is not present, and also delaying the use of the tags after they have been read. It's quite nice to be able to go in the class reading the corresponding tag and see immediately which class it fills. And most of the classes already work like that. `MyVeryAccessibleClass` can also be filled by several differents xml files, which adds complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare your class MyInitClass as a friend of MyVeryAccessibleClass.

Let's see the code in action.

```
class MyVeryAccessibleClass
{
    friend class MyInitClass;
private:
    const std::vector<int> vect_m;
}
```

Now Let's look at the MyInitClass constructor.

```
MyInitClass::init()
{
   MyVeryAccessibleClass* class_l = methodToGetMyVeryAccessibleClassInOneWayOrAnother();
   auto vect_l& = class_l->vect_l;
   vect_l.push_back(importantInt_m);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like your solution, I am just not sure MyInitClass should have access to all members of MyVeryAccessibleClass. But it might still be a better alternative to using const_cast.

Comment: Which one do you think is better considering only the init function needs to modify vect_m:
`friend class MyInitClass;` or `friend void MyInitClass::init()` ?
The second one needs a complete definition of MyInitClass but is more restrictive.

Comment: It depends. But for you I recommend `friend void MyInitClass::init` since you want the class to access only a particular member and this also helps in debugging.